# How to redirect on ASP.Net Core Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages

I am using the new Razor Pages in ASP.Net core 2
Now I need to redirect

I tried this, but the page does not redirect:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {
        string url = "/.auth/login/aad?post_login_redirect_url=" + Request.Query["redirect_url"];

        Redirect(url);
    }
}
```

How to redirect?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You were very close.  These methods need to return an `IActionResult` (or `Task<IActionResult>` for async methods) and then you need to return the redirect.

```
public IActionResult OnGet()
{
    string url = "/.auth/login/aad?post_login_redirect_url=" 
      + Request.Query["redirect_url"];

    return Redirect(url);
}
```

[Razor pages documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio)

However, you have a huge [Open Redirect Attack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/preventing-open-redirection-attacks) because you aren't validating the `redirect_url` variable.  **Don't use this code in production**.

Comment: You can use `LocalRedirect` instead these days to avoid the security issue.

Comment: I would not recommend a method with the description `This type/member supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.`

Answer (score 44):

You can use the IActionResult to return a redirection instead of the requested page.

```
public IActionResult OnGet()
{
     if (!Auth())
     {
         return new RedirectToPageResult("/Portal/Login");
     }
     return Page();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can do it with this code:

```
  public async Task OnGetAsync()
  {
    Response.Redirect("/Panel");
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

Same for pages without cs:

```
@page

@functions
{
    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        string url = "/.auth/login/aad?post_login_redirect_url=" 
          + Request.Query["redirect_url"];

        return Redirect(url);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this directly in razor view.

```
    @{
if (!Context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("Identity/Account/UserMustChangePassword"))
{
     Context.Response.Redirect("Identity/Account/UserMustChangePassword");
}
}
```