# Redirect to another website is not working in ASP.NET Core Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I am simply trying to call:

```
Redirect("https://www.google.com");
```

In an ASP.NET Core Web Application using (Razor Pages). Please note it is the absolute latest template.

Any idea why nothing is happening?

Here is my code in the model for the About page:

```
public class AboutModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {
        Redirect("https://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

Comment: `Redirect` creates a `RedirectResult`, that needs to be returned. Change the return type to `IActionResult` and then `return Redirect(...);`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect on ASP.Net Core Razor Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50281937/how-to-redirect-on-asp-net-core-razor-pages)

Answer (score 0):

You can just do the following in your .cshtml file, like so:

```
@page
@functions
{
    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        return Redirect("https://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

Or if it's an internal page simply:

```
@page
@functions
{
    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        return RedirectToPage("/SomePage", new { area = "SomeArea" });
    }
}
```

Notice that in both scenarios the `Redirect/RedirectToPage` are being returned as an `IActionResult`.

Hope this helps