# .NET Core razor page web app redirect to a new host name

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a .net core app with a default page set to /index.cshtml. The url www.xyz.com redirects to www.xyz.com/index (since it is a default page). I want to handle a incoming request and replace the host name in the url.
Example:- www.xyz.com/x  -->  should redirect to www.abc.com/x.
I donot want to do this in nginx config file. I want to do this in code.

I have a middleware to handle the request

```
public class GetMiddleware
{
    private RequestDelegate _next;


    public GetMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }
    public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var request = context.Request;
        string path = request.Path.ToString();
       if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
        {
            //redirect to new url/path. I want to check if path exists/x or /whatever and redirect to new url/path

        }
        return _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is your question? Please post the code that is giving you trouble. See [ask].

Comment: @JohnWu  i want to redirect the incoming request to my app to a different url(which is outside of my app) if that resource doesnot exist in my app.

Comment: I understand that is what you want. What part of that are you having trouble with? Most of the users here will not write you a solution from scratch, but will help you with your attempt if you have made one.

Comment: @JohnWu added please take a look

Comment: Is this an MVC application? How exactly is this `GetMiddleware` class invoked from the controller? The proper way to do this is to return a [RedirectResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.redirectresult?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) from the action method.

Comment: This is not an mvc app. This is a .net core web application with razor pages

Comment: Perhaps check this link: [How to redirect on ASP.Net Core Razor pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50281937/how-to-redirect-on-asp-net-core-razor-pages)

Comment: @JohnWu i figured it out. I referenced the arrticle below and got what i needed with some modifications https://andrewlock.net/retrieving-the-path-that-generated-an-error-with-the-statuscodepages-middleware/

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the response (Status code 301 and the `Location` header) and return:

```
public class GetMiddleware
{
    private RequestDelegate _next;

    public GetMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Path == "/whatever")
        {
            context.Response.Headers.Add("Location", "https://example.com");
            context.Response.StatusCode = 302;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        return _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```